# failed to deploy Ethereum consortium leader template -Microsoft azure

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum

Yesterday, I was just trying to create an Ethereum Blockchain Service with the default settings. It seems to run for about 5 minutes and then fails at the "vmExtensionLinkedTemplate" resource step. Below is an excerpt of the error that I believe is the most applicable. I have seen several questions with similar errors, but they don't seem to have much of a solution - please let me know how to proceed or what else I can provide further.

> Error details:

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n \"message\": \"{\r\n \\"status\\": \\"Failed\\",\r\n \\"error\\": {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\",\r\n \\"message\\": \\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\",\r\n \\"details\\": [\r\n {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"VMExtensionProvisioningError\\",\r\n \\"message\\": \\"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'newuserscript'. Error message: \\\\"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2\\n[stdout]\\n\\n[stderr]\\n--2018-03-05 04:48:53-- [https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/configure-geth-azureuser.sh\\nResolving](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/configure-geth-azureuser.sh%5C%5CnResolving) gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)... 13.76.135.151\\nConnecting to gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)|13.76.135.151|:443... connected.\\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\\nLength: unspecified [binary/octet-stream]\\nSaving to: ‘configure-geth-azureuser.sh’\\n\\n 0K ... 49.8M=0s\\n\\nLast-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.\\n2018-03-05 04:48:53 (49.8 MB/s) - ‘configure-geth-azureuser.sh’ saved [4069]\\n\\n--2018-03-05 04:48:53-- [https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/deployment-utility.sh\\nResolving](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/deployment-utility.sh%5C%5CnResolving) gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)... 13.76.135.151\\nConnecting to gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)|13.76.135.151|:443... connected.\\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\\nLength: unspecified [binary/octet-stream]\\nSaving to: ‘deployment-utility.sh’\\n\\n 0K ...... 71.6M=0s\\n\\nLast-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.\\n2018-03-05 04:48:53 (71.6 MB/s) - ‘deployment-utility.sh’ saved [6763]\\n\\n\\\\".\\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n \"message\": \"{\r\n \\"status\\": \\"Failed\\",\r\n \\"error\\": {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\",\r\n \\"message\\": \\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\",\r\n \\"details\\": [\r\n {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"VMExtensionProvisioningError\\",\r\n \\"message\\": \\"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'newuserscript'. Error message: \\\\"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2\\n[stdout]\\n\\n[stderr]\\n--2018-03-05 04:48:50-- [https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/configure-geth-azureuser.sh\\nResolving](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/configure-geth-azureuser.sh%5C%5CnResolving) gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)... 13.76.135.151\\nConnecting to gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)|13.76.135.151|:443... connected.\\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\\nLength: unspecified [binary/octet-stream]\\nSaving to: ‘configure-geth-azureuser.sh’\\n\\n 0K ... 266M=0s\\n\\nLast-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.\\n2018-03-05 04:48:50 (266 MB/s) - ‘configure-geth-azureuser.sh’ saved [4069]\\n\\n--2018-03-05 04:48:50-- [https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/deployment-utility.sh\\nResolving](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/deployment-utility.sh%5C%5CnResolving) gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)... 13.76.135.151\\nConnecting to gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)|13.76.135.151|:443... connected.\\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\\nLength: unspecified [binary/octet-stream]\\nSaving to: ‘deployment-utility.sh’\\n\\n 0K ...... 69.8M=0s\\n\\nLast-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.\\n2018-03-05 04:48:50 (69.8 MB/s) - ‘deployment-utility.sh’ saved [6763]\\n\\n\\\\".\\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n \"message\": \"{\r\n \\"status\\": \\"Failed\\",\r\n \\"error\\": {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\",\r\n \\"message\\": \\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\\",\r\n \\"details\\": [\r\n {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"VMExtensionProvisioningError\\",\r\n \\"message\\": \\"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'newuserscript'. Error message: \\\\"Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=2\\n[stdout]\\n\\n[stderr]\\n--2018-03-05 04:48:54-- [https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/configure-geth-azureuser.sh\\nResolving](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/configure-geth-azureuser.sh%5C%5CnResolving) gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)... 13.76.135.151\\nConnecting to gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)|13.76.135.151|:443... connected.\\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\\nLength: unspecified [binary/octet-stream]\\nSaving to: ‘configure-geth-azureuser.sh’\\n\\n 0K ... 323M=0s\\n\\nLast-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.\\n2018-03-05 04:48:54 (323 MB/s) - ‘configure-geth-azureuser.sh’ saved [4069]\\n\\n--2018-03-05 04:48:54-- [https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/deployment-utility.sh\\nResolving](https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20151001/microsoft-azure-blockchain.azure-multi-member-blockchain-serviceethereum-consortium-leader.1.0.7/Artifacts/scripts/deployment-utility.sh%5C%5CnResolving) gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)... 13.76.135.151\\nConnecting to gallery.azure.com (gallery.azure.com)|13.76.135.151|:443... connected.\\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\\nLength: unspecified [binary/octet-stream]\\nSaving to: ‘deployment-utility.sh’\\n\\n 0K ...... 88.2M=0s\\n\\nLast-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.\\n2018-03-05 04:48:54 (88.2 MB/s) - ‘deployment-utility.sh’ saved [6763]\\n\\n\\\\".\\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

I tried from several accounts, but all show the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because Microsoft has moved the implementation of Ethereum Consortium Leader into another Azure Resource, still yet to be identified by me. Prior to the latest Azure releases Ethereum Consortium Leader was a standalone Resource that can be created, but currently this is no longer the case, I can see only:

- Ethereum Proof of Authority Consortium
- Ethereum Proof of Work Consortium

Hope this helps!